# How to differ formsets in django when using modelformset_factory?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Let's say I have an Contact object and I want to have two groups of contact Formsets in django(1.8) divided by **fieldset** tag in html template. I use modelformset_factory. Regardless I use one or two different factory functions, fields in these two formsets have same id in html. Since http.Request.body is dictionary, I lose information about one of the two formsets.

```
contacts_formset = modelformset_factory(
  models.Contact,
  form=forms.ContactDetailForm,
  extra=2)

contacts_escalation_formset_new = contacts_formset(
    queryset=models.Contact.objects.none())

contacts_other_formset_new = contacts_formset(
    queryset=models.Contact.objects.none())
```

in HTML:

```
input id="id_form-0-name" maxlength="155" name="form-0-name" type="text"
input id="id_form-0-name" maxlength="155" name="form-0-name" type="text"
```

For simple django form, there is keyword "prefix=..." . But this factory function does not have this argument. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `modelformset_factory` class returns a FormSet class. This FormSet class has a optional `prefix` argument, similar to Form classes.

```
contacts_escalation_formset_new = contacts_formset(
    prefix='escalation',
    queryset=models.Contact.objects.none(),
)

contacts_other_formset_new = contacts_formset(
    prefix='other'
    queryset=models.Contact.objects.none(),
)
```

See the docs on [using more than one formset in a view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#using-more-than-one-formset-in-a-view) for another example.

Comment: That was quick. And that's correct. I just hit the same django page.